# The preview from the camera in the android application is not displayed

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camerax

I'm trying to write a simple android application to work with the camera, the preview is not displayed.

```
    private fun startCamera() {

        val previewView: PreviewView = viewBinding.viewFinder
        cameraController = LifecycleCameraController(baseContext)
        cameraController.bindToLifecycle(this)
        cameraController.cameraSelector = CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA
        previewView.controller = cameraController

    }
```

Permissions are all received.

Did exactly as in the video CameraX setup and permissions.
I will be glad of any hint...

Comment: Is your view visible? I would checkout the GitHub sample and figure out the difference between those two.